# Error when installing chocolatey on windows 7 64 bits

Tags: chocolatey

Am trying to install chocolatey on windows 7 64 bits. Am using documentation [Here](https://chocolatey.org/install)
when I type the code below in the command prompt.

```
PowerShell Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

it throws the error as shown in the screenshots below

[image: screenshots]

I do not know what the error is all about. I just added **Powershell** infront of the code before i runs it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Chocolatey website requires TLS 1.2 to access it and download the installation script from.

Take a look at [this blog post](https://chocolatey.org/blog/remove-support-for-old-tls-versions) as it explains the change, the commands you can run in PowerShell to see if you're supported and what you can do for older legacy systems (such as Windows 7).

Answer (score 1):

upgrade your power shell version and try i to got this error after upgrading my powershell version this error geon

Answer (score 1):

You need TLS 1.2 or do an offline installation.

**- check for windows update**

**- Download the easy fix here.**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392#bkmk_easy

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Windows Update destroyed my fresh Win7 SP1 x86 evaluation version [downloaded from microsoft.com](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/)

What worked for me was:

- Download the [Easy Fix](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392#bkmk_easy) to enable TLS 1.2
- Download and install [.Net Framework 4.8](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework) (any 4.x should work)
- Download chocolatey nuget file, rename to .zip, extract and run `tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1` [as described in choco docs](https://docs.chocolatey.org/en-us/choco/setup#install-downloaded-nuget-package-from-powershell)
- At this point choco is installed but PowerShell is still 2.x, so run `choco install powershell` to get 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if I ever come back I will document the whole procedure of installing chocolatey to Windows 7.

1. Install all Windows updates.

   1. Check for updates.
   2. Install updates
   3. Reboot
   4. Repeat above steps a million times until there are no new updates (~20 hours).
2. Install NET4.5 if not installed, should be installed.

   - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653
3. Install Windows Management Framework WMF

   - Currently available from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616
   - Documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/installing-windows-powershell?view=powershell-7.2
4. Install powershell

   1. Go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.2
   2. Click `MSI package`
   3. Download and install.
5. Run powershell as administrator.

   1. Install chocolatey from the official link https://chocolatey.org/install
6. Cleanup disc C: to remove all temporary files from windows updates (~7GB in my case)

Comment: Windows update destroyed my Win7 x86. Instead of windows update, download the Easy Fix from Matt Jaf´s answer.